# How do I stop Chrome keeps turning on the feedback in my Bose QC-30 headset?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of Bose QC-30 headphones. They have noise cancelling and when you are in a call, they stop doing the noise cancelling by playing the environment noise into the headphones so you can hear your own voice.

When I have them connected to my computer and when I have Chrome opened, the feedback system gets turned on for 10 seconds every minute or so.

As far as I can see, it doesn't matter which web sites I have opened, it happens even with no websites opened.

Any ideas what's going on? how to stop it?